# Flutter render onto screen like a canvas. How do I achieve this kind of layout?

Tags: flutter, layout, render, floating

Hoping to achieve the following layout. I think making the form (picture 3) would be easy enough, but rendering overlapping elements would be tricky. What would you recommend I use? Is flutter built for this kind of task at all?

[image]

Comment: Just to understand correctly, do you want to render that exact UI or are you saying you want to have a chat UI with the left side possibly overlapping the right depending on the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is actually very easy to do that. Use a [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html). It can take as children [Position Widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html), with which you can specify the position of any widget.

You can try this now with a gist I wrote [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Overlay Widgets")),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                MessageBubble(
                    message: _message, sender: "Fonkam Loic", isMe: true),
                MessageBubble(
                    message: "What is Lorem Ipsum", sender: "You", isMe: false),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final String _message =
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book... ";
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.message, this.sender, this.isMe});
  final String message, sender;
  final bool isMe;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 7.0),
                child: Text(
                  message,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will look into this. Thank you!